# Error occurred after playing last video from parent div by clicking on play image (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple videos been fetched with ajax (dynamically, load more I mean).

All videos play well when play button is clicked from parent div but when last video (or sometimes the first video) is been clicked, the other videos refuses to play when clicked and current clicked video (which is the last) refuses to stop when paused and play button only blink multiple times.

I have been trying to solve this problem but I have been facing difficulties for I have no clue. I need your help.

**JQUERY**

```
// Ajax load more script that fetches videos starts here
// success:function(data) {
// video play/pause
        $('.post_video').parent().click(function() {
          var currentVideo = $(this).children(".post_video").get(0);
          var allVideos = $(".post_video");
          
          allVideos.each(function(){
            if (currentVideo != this)
            this.pause();
          });

          if (currentVideo.paused){        
            currentVideo.play();   
            $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
          } else {       
            currentVideo.pause();
            $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
          }
        });
// }
// Ajax load more script that fetches videos ends here
```

HTML

```
<div class="video_wrapper">
                    <video class="post_video" loop>
                        <source src="videos/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                    <div class="playpause"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: As a test as I would try changing `this` to `$(this)` in your `each` loop. I can't remember if they are the same or not as I haven't used jquery in awhile.

Comment: I got an error in my console `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pause is not a function` after changing `this.pause();` to `$(this).pause();` and also `!= this` to `!= $(this)` @imvain2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like adding duplicate click handlers to your `video_wrapper` when you load more videos.
You should only add the handler to the newly added videos or use event delegation so you don't have to add the handler every time you load more videos.

```
// Use event delegation to attach click handlers outside of ajax
// any reason you select post_video then get their parents instead of just selecting video_wrapper?
$(document).on('click', '.video_wrapper', function() {
    var currentVideo = $(this).children(".post_video").get(0);
    var allVideos = $(".post_video");
      
    allVideos.each(function(){
        if (currentVideo != this)
        this.pause();
    });

    if (currentVideo.paused){        
        currentVideo.play();   
        $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
    } 
    else {       
        currentVideo.pause();
        $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
    }
});
```